# Margin expands in Print View

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm working on a print view for my project but when I change the size of the paper sometimes the margins in the container expand for some reason and it expands the height of my container. Is there any way to fix this?

```
<div class="field-padding">
    <div class="label">{{label}}</div>
    <div class="text-field">{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS file:

```
@media print {
  .field-padding {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

Picture for reference:

[image]

EDIT:
Additional Reference. As you can see here same components inside a section, also in same page but the other one is expanded for some reason. (PRINT VIEW)

Section1

[image]

Section2

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In print mode is better to use cm or pt, See [this](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

```
@media print {
  .field-padding {
    margin-bottom: 11pt;
  }

  .label {
    margin-bottom: 6cm;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh sorry about that let me fix and edit my post. but I do have the dots in my classes in css file but for some reason I dont know why it expands like that given the properties

Comment: Do you have another rules overriding? I see it works

Comment: Hmmm in the parent of my container I see this property:    
 flex: 0 0 50%;
 position: relative;

and that container uses bootstrap col-md

Comment: I see, you need to put units in cm. I update my answer

Comment: It still expands for some reason and when I change the paper size sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I've been stuck with this issue for days now.

Comment: Changing all px to cm/mm/pt in my print worked so thanks for this one!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be cm or mm as a unit when you specify for printing. Can you try like this?.

```
@media print {
    .field-padding {
      margin-bottom: 10mm;
    }

    .label {
      margin-bottom: 5mm;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Used mm/cm/pt in my print view and my problem was fixed.